# How to use custom DNS servers on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a Cloud Run fully managed service that connects to a shared VPC using a connector. This shared VPC is managed by another GCP project and another team, but I can deploy instances to this VPC. This VPC has custom DNS servers that resolve that team's internal resources. Custom DNS servers are not propagated by DHCP to the VPC users. I have access to all internal resources by IP from the Cloud Run container, but can't access them by name without using custom DNS servers.

The issue is that I can not propagate these servers to the container without getting some errors.

I made the following entrypoint script in my container:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e

{
  echo "nameserver 10.80.64.19";
  echo "nameserver 10.80.64.20";
  echo "nameserver 10.80.64.21";
} >> /etc/resolv.conf

exec "$@"
```

This leads to the following file contents on the running container:

```
nameserver 10.80.64.21
nameserver 10.80.64.20
nameserver 10.80.64.19
search google.internal.
nameserver 169.254.169.254
```

(Custom lines added after what my script writes)

Sometimes the last NS server is used and I get errors connecting shared VPC resources by name (like `Failed to resolve 'some-name'`).

How to solve this issue? AFAIK, I need either to use only custom DNS servers or "merge" information from them and from the standard server `169.254.169.254`. How should I do in this case? What are possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution options were suggested by Google support:

The issue with handling at the Cloud Run side is that we cannot overwrite the `resolv.conf` since the networking stuff is being setup by Docker. We have two options to do this:

1. Outbound Forwarding Zone: https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones#creating-forwarding-zones
2. Outbound server policy: https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/policies#create-out

By implementing a Forwarding zone, you instruct cloud DNS that requests for which domain names should go to a specific DNS server. Good option if you have not so many internal zones names served by custom DNS servers.

By implementing an outbound policy, you change the resolution order and you may force sending resolution requests to custom servers first. Once the request reaches the VPC connector, it should go to the metadata server and it should know how to use the outbound server policy.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your own dns client in the code and send queries to the servers of your choosing instead of relying on the servers configured by the system.

For example, in python in order to query dns server 1.1.1.1 for A records (ip addresses) of 'tut.by' resource I'd do (`configure=False` in order to prevent the Resolver to be configured with system-wide values):

```
>>> import dns.resolver
>>> resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
>>> resolver.nameservers.append('1.1.1.1')
>>> response = resolver.resolve('tut.by')
>>> for ip in response:
...     print(ip)
...
178.172.160.4
178.172.160.5
178.172.160.3
178.172.160.2
```

Hope it helps.